# Python Compounded Return Group By

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I am trying to calculate the monthly compounded returns from each stock’s daily returns in python.

My dataset looks like as follows:

```
DATE    STOCK   RETURN  Year    Month
1/1/2020    A   0.02    2020    1
1/1/2020    B   0.03    2020    1
1/2/2020    A   0.04    2020    1
1/2/2020    B   0.05    2020    1
...             
6/30/2020   A   0.01    2020    6
6/30/2020   B   0.03    2020    6
```

I have tried `df. groupby([STOCK','Year',’Month’])[‘RETURN'].apply(cum_returns)` but it doesn’t give the results in group by. Ideally I am trying to get something like:

```
DATE       STOCK CUMULATIVE RETURN
01/2020    A      (1+0.02)*(1+0.04).... (1+rn) / (1/n) 
01/2020    B       same formula above for B daily stock returns
02/20      A
02/20      B
...
06/30     A
06/30     B
```

The function I was using was:

```
def cum_returns (x):
    a = x.add(1).cumprod()
    a.iloc[0] = 1
    return a
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Can You provide a bit more data and expected result set?

Comment: Sure. For Stock A the returns for Jan 2020 is 0.02,0.01, 0.04 - and for Stock B returns are 0.03,0.01,0.04 - I am trying to calculate the compounded return as for Stock A : (1+0.02)*(1+0.01)*(1+0.04) ^(1/3) -1 and for Stock B - (1+0.03)*(1+0.01)*(1+0.04)^(1/3) -1. I want to iterate it for each month so if Feb 2020, stock A return is 0.05,0.02,0.01,0.04 the compounded return will be 1.05*1.02*1.01*1.04^(1/4)-1 and do the same analysis for Feb, March etc

Comment: So You want to calculate geometric mean  of daily returns per every month and stock? The result will have only one row per (stock, month) ? See: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/geometricmean.asp

Comment: Yes indeed,geometric return of stock per month

Comment: Ok, but why in your example in comment there are different number of days: 3 in Jan and 4 in Feb?

Comment: That was an imaginary dataset, the posted solution is what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, I guessed that :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume we have dataframe:

```
DATE STOCK RETURN Year Month
1/1/2020 A 0.02 2020 1
2/1/2020 A 0.01 2020 1
3/1/2020 A 0.04 2020 1
1/1/2020 B 0.03 2020 1
2/1/2020 B 0.01 2020 1
3/1/2020 B 0.04 2020 1
1/2/2020 A 0.05 2020 2
2/2/2020 A 0.02 2020 2
3/2/2020 A 0.01 2020 2
4/2/2020 A 0.04 2020 2
1/2/2020 B 0.01 2020 2
2/2/2020 B 0.03 2020 2
3/2/2020 B 0.02 2020 2
4/2/2020 B 0.05 2020 2
```

To calculate geometric mean of daily returns ([check definition](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/geometricmean.asp)) per every month and stock use:

```
df.groupby(['STOCK','Year','Month'])[['RETURN']].apply(lambda g: ((g+1).cumprod()**(1/len(g))-1).iloc[-1])
```

result:

```
                    RETURN
STOCK Year Month          
A     2020 1      0.023258
           2      0.029879
B     2020 1      0.026591
           2      0.027394
```

You can check manually if calculation is correct, for example for stock A and Jan:

`(1.02*1.01*1.04)**(1/3)-1 = 0.023258`

Note that `iloc[-1]` in lambda function select last calculated return per group.